# Reference request: Bohr's non-card bluffing game

Tags: probability, reference-request, game-theory, poker

Can anyone provide a reference where Niels Bohr's proposed game is described?

From George Gamow, *One Two Three... Infinity* (Bantam, New York), p. 212:

> Although this bluffing [at poker] actually is the heart of the game,
>   and once led the famous Danish physicist Niels Bohr to propose an
>   entirely new type of game in which no cards are used, and the players
>   simply bluff one another by talking about the imaginary combinations
>   they have, it lies entirely outside the domain of probability
>   calculus, being a purely psychological matter.

Comment: Haveyou seen this?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_(play)

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thanks. I see the the personal anecdote about Bohr ("invisible straight"). It seems that Gamow had something more specific in mind.